# How to prevent crash when ViewController viewWillDisappear is called and a callback is still running

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, afnetworking-2

in a ViewController, that hosts a TableView, I load the data for the table view using AFNetworking in viewDidLoad.

This can take a couple of seconds. If during the network call, the users swipes back to the previous VC, the app crashes. I think it is because the network call is still running, comes back and the original callback for the network call is somehow lost?

I started using stuff like "userInteractionEnabled = false" and setting it back to true when the data finished loading or setting a global variable in viewWillDisappear and checking this in the callback. This works but seems quite wrong.

1. What is the proper method/func to load data for a table view?
2. How is a situation like this properly handled, e.g. should I cancel all AFNetworking request in viewWillDisappear?

Thanks a lot for a hint!

Comment: Have you think on showing a loading alert while the user interaction is disabled? If the user wants to see that table view that take some seconds to load, I think he will wait for it. 

On the other hand, if you don't want to make him wait, propably you are in the correct way (canceling the request before the controller is active).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I've done, nonetheless it seems a bit strange...